# SQL SERVER: generic trigger for log\save record Update in table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

i want create a trigger, would be easy to move it to other\new tables,
to save into **One Table** for all Db, for each Update, the values:

- Table Name
- Column Name
- Old Value
- New Value

What has been tried? Nothing :(
Because:

1. the trigger gives a list of records: DELETED, INSERTED.
2. also the Functions UPDATE(ColName) & COLUMNS_UPDATED() Let me know **per line**
   Which columns were changed.

**The question is:** join 1 with 2...

How can I extract from each line only the values ​​of the modified columns with Their names?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Bad idea....  you would have such a slow performing system it would be ugly and a constant maintenance headache.  Most people try to avoid triggers.  SQL Server either has or is coming out with an audit table.    However if you insist you want to create PROCEDURES that do what you spec'd earlier and CALL them from triggers.

Comment: thank, @T McKeown. but also with PROCEDURE I can not